# In HTML + CSS: Force text to max two rows, increase the width

Tags: html, css, text, flexbox

I have a horizontal timeline made with list (`li`) elements that has `display:flex;` at it's parent attribute. That make the list horizontal. But I want the texts to be maximum two rows in the boxes.

So for example, I want this:

> The first
>
> asphalt is
>
> delivered.

To become this:

> The first  asphalt
>
> is delivered.

I want that to be a rule and the width can become as wide as it need to be.

And I have seen a lot of examples where the solution is to work with `overflow:hidden`. But that's not what I looking for. I wanna know if there is a way to get a dynamic width so all the text is visible.

**Edit:**

Here is the snippet:

```css
.left-arrow,.right-arrow {
  float:left;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  margin-top:20px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.left-arrow {
  border-right:20px solid black;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
.right-arrow {
  border-left:20px solid black;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.timeline {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  margin: 0 5px;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 60px);
  overflow-x: scroll;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.timeline li {
  width: 300px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.timeline li a {
  color: #000;
}
.timestamp {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px 10px 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.status {
  padding: 10px 5px 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border-top: 3px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}
.status:before {
  content: "";
  width: 4px;
  height: 8px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: calc(50% - (4px / 2));
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="left-arrow" data-role="none"></a>
<ul class="timeline" id="timeline">
  <li>
    <a href="#pop-1910-20">
      <div class="timestamp">1910-20</div>
      <div class="status">The founder buys land.</div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#pop-1928">
      <div class="timestamp">1928</div>
      <div class="status">The refinery goes into operation.</div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#pop-1929">
      <div class="timestamp">1929</div>
      <div class="status">The first asphalt is delivered.</div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#pop-1931">
      <div class="timestamp">1931</div>
      <div class="status">New cracker.</div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#pop-1939-45">
      <div class="timestamp">1939-45</div>
      <div class="status">Central role for the national sales</div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#pop-1950s">
      <div class="timestamp">1950-talet</div>
      <div class="status">The network of petrol stations is being expanded</div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#pop-1956">
      <div class="timestamp">1956</div>
      <div class="status">The second refinery is finished</div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#pop-1958">
      <div class="timestamp">1958</div>
      <div class="status">The founder dies.</div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#pop-1960">
      <div class="timestamp">1960</div>
      <div class="status">Risky sales strategy</div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#pop-1967-69">
      <div class="timestamp">1967-69</div>
      <div class="status">Increased capacity of bitumen</div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#pop-1974">
      <div class="timestamp">1974</div>
      <div class="status">The energy crisis leads to financial crisis</div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
<a href="#" class="right-arrow" data-role="none"></a>
```

Comment: edit your question, hit CTRL + M and put all of the html and css you have in the snippet box

Answer (score 1):

We can also fix the two lines for li elements by fixing the height and and line-height by halve of it. So two lines only can come but width can be maximum. So that there will be two lines but it would expand on x side. It will be something like this link below.

```css
.twolines{
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="twolines">Hello World. If it has two lines but have max width it can to be produced so that it will not expanded. Some extra text will be truncated when even two lines exceeded</li>
<li class="twolines">Hello World. If it has two lines but have max width it can to be produced so that it will not expanded.</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: But your li elements are not horizontal next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Taken your code snippet and used the same logic of height and line-height. Along with that used box-sizing border box as there was some alignment (like padding and boader) so the width will be controlled including those also.Now only two lines and taken width accrodingly.

```css
.left-arrow,.right-arrow {
  float:left;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  margin-top:20px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.left-arrow {
  border-right:20px solid black;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
.right-arrow {
  border-left:20px solid black;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.timeline {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  margin: 0 5px;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 60px);
  overflow-x: scroll;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.timeline li {
  width: 300px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.timeline li a {
  color: #000;
}
.timestamp {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px 10px 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.status {
  padding: 10px 5px 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border-top: 3px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 43px;
  line-height: 15px;
  width: 213px;
}
.status:before {
  content: "";
  width: 4px;
  height: 8px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: calc(50% - (4px / 2));
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="left-arrow" data-role="none"></a>
<ul class="timeline" id="timeline">
  <li>
    <a href="#pop-1910-20">
      <div class="timestamp">1910-20</div>
      <div class="status">The founder buys land.</div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#pop-1928">
      <div class="timestamp">1928</div>
      <div class="status">The refinery goes into operation.</div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#pop-1929">
      <div class="timestamp">1929</div>
      <div class="status">The first asphalt is delivered.</div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#pop-1931">
      <div class="timestamp">1931</div>
      <div class="status">New cracker.</div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#pop-1939-45">
      <div class="timestamp">1939-45</div>
      <div class="status">Central role for the national sales</div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#pop-1950s">
      <div class="timestamp">1950-talet</div>
      <div class="status">The network of petrol stations is being expanded</div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#pop-1956">
      <div class="timestamp">1956</div>
      <div class="status">The second refinery is finished</div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#pop-1958">
      <div class="timestamp">1958</div>
      <div class="status">The founder dies.</div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#pop-1960">
      <div class="timestamp">1960</div>
      <div class="status">Risky sales strategy</div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#pop-1967-69">
      <div class="timestamp">1967-69</div>
      <div class="status">Increased capacity of bitumen</div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#pop-1974">
      <div class="timestamp">1974</div>
      <div class="status">The energy crisis leads to financial crisis</div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
<a href="#" class="right-arrow" data-role="none"></a>
```

Comment: Well, setting it to a fixed width is of course an option. But I had hoped to have a dynamic width. That adjusts to the length of the text. So small text becomes small width.

Comment: Yes we can control width according to the text content through js. Other option we can arrange the li elements as inline instead of float left so we can have scroll from the left arrow to right arrow.